# Memorize the position of RadioButton

Tags: java, android

The bottom line is, there is a main activity, and 4 fragments one of the fragments is something like settings.
In the markup of the fragment with the RadioGroup and 3 RadioButton settings, the positions of which must correspond to the starting fragment, ie the first, second or third. It is necessary to make sure that when the application is closed, the positions of the pressed RadioButtons are saved and the required fragment is displayed in accordance with the position.

Code activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FragmentRoute froute;
    FragmentSearch fSearch;
    FragmentHelp fHelp;
    FragmentSearchRoute fSearchRoute;
    FragmentSettings fSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        fSearch = new FragmentSearch ();
        froute = new FragmentRoute();
        fHelp = new FragmentHelp();
        fSettings = new FragmentSettings();
        fSearchRoute = new FragmentSearchRoute();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentRoute(), "test").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.route) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, froute);
        } else if (id == R.id.search) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fSearch);

        } else if (id == R.id.search_route) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fSearchRoute);
        } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fSettings);
        } else if (id == R.id.help) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fHelp);
        }ft.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Code Fragment-settings

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    RadioButton radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr5);
        View rv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);


        return rv;
    }

}
```

Comment: Save position of `radiobutton` in `sharedPreferences`.

Comment: Need an example of use

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Could you give an example code with RadioButton. Very necessary. I'm just new to android programming and it's hard to understand right away what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Use `SharedPreferences` to store the selected `RadioButton` position.

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr5);
        View rv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) rv.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // Required to get the checked RadioButton id
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                int selectedPosition;

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton1:
                        selectedPosition = 1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2:
                        selectedPosition = 2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton3:
                        selectedPosition = 3;
                        break;
                    default:
                        selectedPosition = 1;
                        break;
                }

                // Store in SharedPreferences
                editor.putInt("SELECTED_POSITION", selectedPosition);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        return rv;
    }
}
```

**2.** In your `Main2Activity`, `onCreate()` method get `SELECTED_POSITION` value from `SharedPreferences` and show your desired `Fragment`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ........
    ...............

    fSearch = new FragmentSearch();
    froute = new FragmentRoute();
    fHelp = new FragmentHelp();
    fSettings = new FragmentSettings();
    fSearchRoute = new FragmentSearchRoute();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int selectedPosition = sharedPreferences.getInt("SELECTED_POSITION", 1);

    switch (selectedPosition) {
        case 1:
            // FragmentSearch
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fSearch).commit();            
            break;
        case 2:
            // FragmentRoute
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, froute).commit();            
            break;
        case 3:
            // FragmentHelp
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fHelp).commit();            
            break;                       
        default:
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fSearch).commit(); 
            break;
    }

}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you very much I'm glad that you helped me.

Comment: Happy to help you :)